# React/Javascript, can't access fields in object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, key, promise, render

I am building a component in React, and passing a `user` object through the props. In the render method, I call `{this.props.user}` and get `5huttotw@gmail.comhuttotwHello, world!` back as a string in the view, which is what is expected (I suppose). However, I cannot access `this.props.user.email` or any of the other fields in the object.

When the object is outputted to the console, it looks like this:

```
Object
 bio: "Hello, world!"
 email: "huttotw@gmail.com"
 first_name: ""
 id: 5
 last_name: ""
 username: "huttotw"
 Object Prototype
```

The fields are there, but when I try to access one of them, I get

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.user.email')

**Note:** I put a `console.log(this.props.user)` before the `return` in the `render` method. It logs twice, once `null` and once as an `Object`.

My render method:

```
render() {
        console.log(this.props.user); // Outputs null then the Object
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div className="panel panel-primary">
                        <div className="panel-body">
                            <h3>Congratulations!</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li>Your token is: <strong>{this.props.token.access_token}</strong></li>
                                <li>Your refresh token is: <strong>{this.props.token.refresh_token}</strong></li>
                                <li>Your scope is: <strong>{this.props.token.scope}</strong></li>
                                <li>Your token expires in: <strong>{this.props.token.expires_in}</strong></li>
                            </ul>
                            <p>{this.props.user.email}</p> // Type Error null is not an object.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

I am using the same strategy for the tokens, but the difference is the `user` object is the result of an API call, the `token` is in local storage.

Both props come from an `AuthenticatedComponent` which keeps track of `tokens` and `users` to know if a user is logged in or not. The `token` and `user` are kept in a store, but if the user is not in a store yet, we have to retrieve it from the database after login.

*How can I wait until the object is there before trying to access it in the view?*

Comment: It sounds like you are rendering the component twice and not passing the user object the first time. Either make your component work without data or don't render it if no data is available.

Comment: How do I only make it render if data is available?

Comment: Assuming this is composed in another component: `{user ? <MyComponent user={user} /> : null}`

Comment: Thanks, that works, if you would post that as an answer I will accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are rendering the component twice and not passing the user object the first time.

Either make your component work without data or don't render it if no data is available. The latter is preferable. All this is is based on the assumption that the component is rendered when the user data is available.

Assuming this component is composed by another component, you can do this easily within JSX using the conditional operator:

```
let user = // get user data

return (
  <div>
    // possible other components
    // ...
    {user ?                          // if user is available
       <MyComponent user={user} /> : // render component
       null                          // otherwise render null
    } 
  </div>
);
```

If your logic is more complex, use an `if` statement:

```
let user = // get user data
let userComponent = null;

if (user) {
   // whatever other complex logic
   userComponent = <MyComponent user={user} />;
}

return (
  <div>
    // possible other components
    // ...
    {userComponent} 
  </div>
);
```

Note that none of this is React or JSX specific. All you are doing here is to decide (with standard JavaScript) which value to pass: a React component or `null`.